# change a value in an excel sheet from c#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to change a specific value in an excel sheet from c#. When I print the value of the cell changed it gives me the new one, but when i re-run the code or if i checked real excel sheet the old value is still there. My code is as the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Now enter please the new password:");
string newpass = Console.ReadLine();                                    
currentWorksheet.Cells[2,1].Value = newpass;
Console.WriteLine(currentWorksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value.ToString());
```

Am i missing something and why excel sheet isn't really changing??
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you *save* the worksheet after the modification?

Comment: I want to change the value from c#, I'm not changing anything manually from excel to save it.

Comment: As @Heinzi stated you should at the end of the modifications save those as a new or same workbook.

Comment: @y.h each time you run your code you load the Workbook in memory as it was. Its happens also manually, if you open an worksheet change it and close (without saving) / finish code, the modifications will be lost

Comment: Ok thank you, i added 'package.Save();' and it works..

Comment: @y.h: That's good to hear. I've added my comment as an answer, as a reference for others with that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously manipulate the Excel file using some kind of Excel library. You modify the value, but you do not *save* the file.

Check the documentation of your library, there should be some kind of `Save` command to save the modified Excel sheet back to disk.